# Nullpointerexception when trying to use dynamically created imagebutton

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences

I am making an app where the user can purchase buildings (imagebuttons) that use the drag and drop API. When a new buildings is purchased, the id of the building is stored using shared preferences so that when the app is opened back up, it is known that it was purchased and the coordinates are saved so the building can be loaded where it was left off. My issue right now is that before a building is created, the ID is null, so I get a nullpointerexception because it knows that it is null. I will post the code and the logcat so you see my problem.

Here is the code checking if the building exists or not:

```
prefs = getSharedPreferences("Buildings", MODE_PRIVATE);
newColonyHutID = prefs.getInt("NewColonyHut", 0);
if (newColonyHutID != 0)
{
    prefs = getSharedPreferences("Coordinates", MODE_PRIVATE);
    colonyHutX = prefs.getInt("ColonyHutX", 0);
    colonyHutY = prefs.getInt("ColonyHutY", 0);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "X: " + colonyHutX + " Y: " + colonyHutY, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    newColonyHutFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.bottomHalf);
    newColonyHut = new ImageButton(runGraphics.this);
    newColonyHut.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mainhut);
    newColonyHut.setX(colonyHutX);
    newColonyHut.setY(colonyHutY);
    newColonyHut.setTag("NewColonyHut");
    newColonyHut.setOnTouchListener(new BuildingsClick());
    findViewById(R.id.topHalf).setOnDragListener(new ColonyHutDrag(getApplicationContext()));
    findViewById(R.id.bottomHalf).setOnDragListener(new ColonyHutDrag(getApplicationContext()));
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams  param1 = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    newColonyHutFrame.addView(newColonyHut, param1);
}//end if
```

Here is the code where the building is created and the id is saved:

```
newColonyHutFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.bottomHalf);
newColonyHut = new ImageButton(runGraphics.this);
newColonyHut.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mainhut); 
prefs = getSharedPreferences("Buildings", MODE_PRIVATE);
if (v.getId() != 0)
{
    Editor edit= prefs.edit();
    edit.putInt("NewColonyHut", newColonyHut.getId());
    edit.commit();
}//end if
newColonyHut.setTag("NewColonyHut");
newColonyHut.setOnTouchListener(new BuildingsClick());
findViewById(R.id.topHalf).setOnDragListener(new ColonyHutDrag(getApplicationContext()));
findViewById(R.id.bottomHalf).setOnDragListener(new ColonyHutDrag(getApplicationContext()));
FrameLayout.LayoutParams  param = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
newColonyHutFrame.addView(newColonyHut, param);
```

Here is the logcat:

```
07-27 20:55:41.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16530): FATAL EXCEPTION: main    
07-27 20:55:41.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16530): Process: com.twentytwentythree.sab, PID: 16530
07-27 20:55:41.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16530): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.twentytwentythree.sab/com.project.llb.runGraphics}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.ImageButton.getId()' on a null object reference
07-27 20:55:41.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16530):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2596)
07-27 20:55:41.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16530):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2653)
07-27 20:55:41.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16530):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
07-27 20:55:41.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16530):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
07-27 20:55:41.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16530):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-27 20:55:41.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16530):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
07-27 20:55:41.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16530):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
07-27 20:55:41.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16530):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-27 20:55:41.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16530):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:852)
07-27 20:55:41.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16530):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:668)
07-27 20:55:41.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16530): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.ImageButton.getId()' on a null object reference
07-27 20:55:41.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16530):    at com.twentytwentythree.sab.runGraphics.onCreate(runGraphics.java:2131)
07-27 20:55:41.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16530):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5312)
07-27 20:55:41.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16530):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
07-27 20:55:41.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16530):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2552)
07-27 20:55:41.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16530):    ... 9 more
```

I have no idea why I would be getting a nullpointerexception here if I am making sure that button is not refreshed if the id is nonexistent.

Please let me know what you think. Any help is appreciated. Thanks guys.

Comment: In the constructor for the ImageButton, what is runGraphics.this? Is this supposed to be the Context? try replacing it with getApplicationContext() as you did with the Toast.

Also, where are you calling getId()? Because it looks like you are calling it on a null object, which would be explained by the above probelm. Can you post your entire class?

Comment: @cjbrooks12 I added where the buildings are created and the IDs are saved. Also, runGraphics.this is the class that the imagebutton is created in.

Comment: does runGraphics extend one of the activity classes? Because each View needs to take the Context of the activity it resides in, not the Java class. Try changing runGraphics.this to getApplicationContext() and see if that works. If not, it would be helpful if you would post your entire class file.

Comment: @cjbrooks12 Well I tried using getApplicationContext() instead of runGraphics.this and nothing changed. I can't quite post the whole class because it is pretty lengthy. I don't know what else would be relevant to this exact problem. I just can't figure out why I would be getting a nullpointerexception for the getId if I am not getting there if it is in an if statement checking if it is equal to zero.

Comment: Well part of it is that you are checking one object, v, for null, but you are calling getId() on newColonyHut. It may be the case that v is not null, but newColonyHut is, so maybe you mean to save the id from v, or check if newColonyHut is null? At any rate, your ImageButton is not being initialized correctly, and I don't know why

Comment: @saboehnke what is on line 2131 of runGraphics java

Answer (score 0):

You are Checking v!=0 in this case while what i think is that what you are checking for v.getId where v is being returned as null

```
newColonyHutFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.bottomHalf);
newColonyHut = new ImageButton(runGraphics.this);
newColonyHut.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mainhut); 
prefs = getSharedPreferences("Buildings", MODE_PRIVATE);
 // THIS IS WHAT YOU HAVE TO DO 
if(v!=null){
```

if (v.getId() != 0)
    {
    Editor edit= prefs.edit();
    edit.putInt("NewColonyHut", newColonyHut.getId());
    edit.commit();
    }//end if

```
}
newColonyHut.setTag("NewColonyHut");
newColonyHut.setOnTouchListener(new BuildingsClick());
findViewById(R.id.topHalf).setOnDragListener(new               ColonyHutDrag(getApplicationContext()));
findViewById(R.id.bottomHalf).setOnDragListener(new             ColonyHutDrag(getApplicationContext()));
FrameLayout.LayoutParams  param = new    FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,   FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
newColonyHutFrame.addView(newColonyHut, param);
```